# C++ Simple class program wont compile. Did i mess up the include headers? 'Error redefinition of a class'

Tags: c++, class, object, compilation

I just have a simple program where dice.cpp and dice.h run through game.cpp to as of now just compute the sum of two dice rolls.

When I try to run the program apparently I am redefining the Dice class, that is what my error is telling me.

Here are my three files.

**game.cpp**

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ int sum;
  Dice dice1;
  Dice dice2;
  dice1.roll();
  dice2.roll();
  sum = dice1.getFace() + dice2.getFace();
  cout << sum;

  return 0;

}
```

**dice.cpp**

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
#include "Dice.h"
using namespace std;
// g++ -c Dice.cpp

// default constructor: initializes the face of a new
// Dice object to 1

Dice::Dice()
{
  //cout <<  "Default constructor " << endl;
  face = 1; // not redeclaring the data member face
}


// specific constructor: initializes the face of a new
// Dice object to newFace
// Pre-condition: newFace is a valid number
// call setFace function inside Dice(int newFace)
Dice::Dice(int newFace)
{
    //cout << "Specific constructor " << endl;
    setFace(newFace);
}


// Sets face to the value in otherFace
// Pre-condition: otherFace is valid
void Dice::setFace(int otherFace)
{
    assert(otherFace >= 1 && otherFace <= 6);
    face = otherFace;
}


// Changes the value of face to a random value between 1 and 6
void Dice::roll()
{
  face = rand()%6 +1;
}

// returns the face value of a Dice object
int Dice::getFace() const
{
    return face;
}

    // displays the face value of a Dice object
void Dice::display() const
{
     cout << "This dice has " << face << " on top" << endl;
}
#endif
```

**Dice.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// definition of class Dice
class Dice
{
  private:

    int face; // can only take values between 1 and 6

  public:

    // default constructor: initializes the face of a new
    // Dice object to 1
    Dice();

  // specific constructor: initializes the face of a new
    // Dice object to newFace
    // Pre-condition: newFace is a valid number
    // call setFace function inside Dice(int newFace)
    Dice(int newFace);

    // Sets face to the value in otherFace
    // Pre-condition: otherFace is valid
    void setFace(int otherFace);

    // Changes the value of face to a random value between 1 and 6
    void roll();

    // returns the face value of a Dice object
    int getFace() const;

    // displays the face value of a Dice object
    void display() const;

};
```

[HERE IS A PHOTO OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbpxG.png)

Comment: Why do you header include guards in the *source* file, but none in the actual header file?

Comment: `**class Dice**` ? What's with the `**` ?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the *actual* errors, in full, unedited, and including any possible informational notes.

Comment: Put include guard in the headers, not wher you include these.

Answer (score 2):

In "dice.cpp" file, remove the third line which says "#include "dice.h".
You are already defining the dice class and hence you don't need the #include statement

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is lying. The error seems to say that `game.cpp` includes `Dice.h`, and that `Dice.h` includes `Dice.cpp`, which includes `Dice.h`. So your `Dice.h` header file is included twice, and with no [header include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in the *header file* the class will be defined twice.

Simple solution? Don't include the *source* file. You should still have header include guards in the header file though.